# Unable to access model data from action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller:

```
class Api::V1::Account::SharingController < ApplicationController
  def show
    sharings = Account::Sharing.all
    render json: sharings, status: :ok
  end
end
```

The model:

```
path: models/account/sharing.rb
class Account::Sharing < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Route:

```
scope '/account' do
  resource :sharing, controller: 'account.sharing', path: 'sharings'
end
```

I get the this error: `uninitialized constant Api::V1::Account::SharingController::Account`, this is because of `sharings = Account::Sharing.all`

In rails console, I am able to use and get data with: `Account::Sharing.all`

Why is this happening?

UPDATE

Changes the folder to `accounts` and now my `SharingController` sits in `accounts/sharing_controller.rb` and is working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the controller it searches for `Account::Sharing` in the controller's namespace. Try prefixing it with `::` to tell it to search from the 'root' namespace like so:

```
::Account::Sharing.all
```

Answer (score 0):

yuo need to define routes like that.

```
scope '/api' do
  scope '/v1' do
    scope '/accounts' do
      resource :sharing, controller: 'account.sharing', path: 'sharings'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: they are defined like that, also having 'account.sharing' is not working, because of the `.`